# What is the best way to handle drop down items in symfony form based on item status?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

Let's consider a scenario like below:

Entity Car has Many To Many CarType which is a list of different types and each type can be active or inactive.

Car Form:

```
$builder->add('type', 'entity', array(
            'label'         => 'Car Type',
            'class'         => 'SomeBundle:CarType',
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                $qb = $er->createQueryBuilder('type')
                        ->where('type.status = :status')
                        ->setParameter('status', 'active')
                ;
                return $qb;
            }
        ));
```

In create phase, a user create a `Car` with an active `Type`. Assume I have an admin page to mark `Type` active/inactive.

What is the best way to handle the `Car` edit phase that has a relationship to an inactive `Type`? In other word if a `Car` has a relationship to any `Type` that was active at some point and not active any more, the choice would not show up in the dropdown.

What is the best way to handle a use case like this which dropdwon items can have different status in different time frame but query only returns the active ones?

One way would be to alert the user that `Car` is using some inactive `Type` but is there any other better way?

Comment: Think about what an inactive type means in real world terms. Does it makes  sense (in your application's domain) for a car to change it's type after it's creation? If the answer is no, maybe you should not render the `type` field while editing. If the answer is yes, what do you expect to happen to those cars that now have an inactive type? Many times properties called 'type' indicates bad OOP design, maybe you should have entities like `Sedan`, `Convertible`, etc...

Comment: @RenanTaranto If the admin create a car, make a typo. He can't change the type of the car?

Comment: @goto Actually his question is about how to deal with it in the normal users perspective, not for the admin. What I mean is that in order to achieve a good solution for these scenarios we should analyze each entity context in the application. There's no final and single answer for this question.

Comment: Let's assume in my context it make sense to change the car type.

Comment: @PMoubed If it is an application for a car customization shop for example,  you could have a button named "Customize to Convertible" instead of rendering the type fields. In this fictional context, an inactive type means that the shop doesn´t perform that modification anymore and you wont expect the cars with an inactive type to change it when it becomes inactive.

Answer (score 0):

You ca deal with the problem in the admin level 
(like you can't make inactive a carType if he's still used)

Or you deal it with user level:
You propose only choices of active car + the inactive current user choice.
This way the user can only choose to change to an active type of car or keep it's outdated type

```
$qb = $er->createQueryBuilder('type')
    ->where('type.status = :status')
    ->orWhere('id = :currentTypeId')
    ->setParameter('currentTypeId', $someId)
    ->setParameter('status', 'active')
```

;